# Updating Firebase Database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So im making an application where i want to update users info on a Firebase Database. I have no problem when I create new data but when i want to change values in the table I get a runtime error. The weird thing is that it will update the table about one in 10 attempts which really confuses me. Here is the code:

```
 func updateDatabase(){


    let colors: [String : AnyObject] = ["colorOne" : "blue"  , "colorTwo" : "pink" ]

    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    databaseRef.child("users").child(myAccount.userUID).child("lastColor").updateChildValues(colors)


}
```

And the runtime error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''

but as far i can tell I dont have any empty strings or have any invalid characters.

Comment: I've also tried the setValue method which will create a value when there is no reference but has the same error if i try to change an existing one in the database

Answer (score 0):

I found it! Turns i didn't set the userUID variable in the func. I added that and it worked. Simple mistake